# Preserve ability to set FACL

Tags: linux, file-permissions, acl

Using setfacl on linux, seems like only `owner` (and `root`) can modify the ACL via setfacl, is that right?

If there is a directory owned by `joe` and `joe` grants `rwx` to `marry`, she can read any file, create new, delete old, make directory trees, etc. Everything seems to be fine, they share the content and can update each other's files.

But `joe` just wants to have ability to set ANY ACL, so in future he would like to allow `linda` to share his directory. But this is allowed only for the files he owns, so `mary's` files and directories are not accessible to change permission on.

The questions are:

- Is there a permission to change permission on ACL (anything else than rwx)?
- Is there any method how to set the owner of files/directories created by `mary`/`linda` to `joe` automagically via any ACL setup (repressive applying of `chown -R` fails for files not owned by `joe`)?

**Edit**
*@grawity:* I cannot comment, so I'll edit and try to explain the motivation here: the main point is that `joe` as the "shared directory manager" and owner wants to incrementally add/remove subsequent users (for simplicity all having the same `rwx` permissions):

```
setfacl -d -m u:linda:rwx
setfacl -m u:linda:rwx
```

He cannot create/alter any group, he is just regular user with `uid > 0`. I thought of transfering the **ownership** only, not the permissions. Imagine `linda` now creates a directory. New member `jack` enters the club, asks `joe` to add him to the list. But `joe` cannot alter other than his own directories... So `jack` cannot access files created by `linda`. `joe` would have to ask her to set permissions etc.

It might make more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a permission to change permission on ACL (anything else than rwx)?

No, not in POSIX ACLs. Just like classic POSIX permission bits, only the owner may change them.

(It exists in Windows/NTFS/CIFS/NFSv4 ACLs, but that's mostly only relevant on FreeBSD anyway.)

> Is there any method how to set the owner of files/directories created by mary/linda to joe automagically via any ACL setup (repressive applying of chown -R fails for files not owned by joe)?

No. However, I don't understand how it would help with sharing files; if anything, it'd only be worse – Mary creates a file but can't do anything with it until Joe grants access; meanwhile, Joe automatically gets access to all files created by Mary even if they weren't explicitly shared. This makes zero sense.

Setting *default* ACLs on the directory (`u:joe:rwx,u:mary:rwx,u:linda:rwx` or even `g:family:rwx`) should be enough for this purpose.